# How to apply complex odata filters programatically with kendo data sources?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, datasource

I have a kendo data source (attached to a grid in case it matters) that's an OData v4 endpoint source.
I need to apply something like this filter to it ...

LINQ query:

```cs
ds.data().Where(i => i.References.Any(r => r.OfferLines.Any(l => l.OfferId == "myOfferId"))
```

OData query:

```
?$filter=References/any(r:r/OfferLines/any(l:l/OfferId eq 'myOfferId'))
```

how can i do this using teleriks documented function dataSource.filter "after my grid has been initialised" programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *parameterMap* event to inject custom filter. Here is an example of my code using to filter articles by several or conditions.

```
dataSource: {
    type: "odata-v4",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: "/oData/Article",
        parameterMap: function (data) {
            //Get value used to filter
            var value = data.filter.filters[0].value;
            //Generate parameters in odata v4 format
            var d = kendo.data.transports['odata-v4'].parameterMap(data);
            //Add filter by matching any reference containing value
            d.$filter = "References/any(ref: contains(tolower(ref/Reference),'" + value + "')))";
            return d;
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Close enough to what I was trying to achieve!